# Rails 4 and Leaflet: assets/images not found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, leaflet, asset-pipeline

I am having a problem that really should not be a problem. For some reason the images I have in app/assets/images are not accessable. When I request them I just get a 404.

```
./log/development.log:Started GET "/assets/images/marker-shadow.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-20 22:02:38 -0400
./log/development.log:ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/marker-shadow.png"):

mike@sleepycat:~/projects/myapp$ ls app/assets/images/
marker-icon-2x.png  marker-icon.png  marker-shadow.png
```

This really should be a braindead easy fix... restarting the server at most.
I have restarted the server, I have checked the file permissions to make sure the files have sane permissions on them... and I still get 404's when I load my page.

What am I missing here?

Using Rails 4.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just get your image with this helper :

```
image_path('marker-shadow.png')
```

The path generated by rails is "/assets/marker-shadow.png" without the 'images' folder.

Comment: Ugh. That was it. Leaflet.js was requesting the default icon when I created a marker on the map, but Leaflet does not know about Rails asset pipeline stuff. I had to specify a custom icon with an iconUrl that uses the image_path helper. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to display the images in a view, then you have to use image_path in conjunction with image_tag. image_path() only returns the pathname of the image file. So, you would do this:  image_tag image_path('your_image.png')

Comment: I'm still experiencing the same problems. If you're integrating leaflet into the rails project, shouldn't we be placing them in the `vendor` folder instead? What's the proper way to precompile everything with the files in the `vendor` folder and have the right path access across all the default leaflet files? It's working in my development environment, but production is experiencing the same issue after precompile.

Answer (score 8):

all you have in `app/assets/images/` folder you can access with direct path

```
'/assets/marker-icon-2x.png'
...
```

there is asset helper for this to use it inside erb:

```
asset_path('marker-icon-2x.png')
```

for images inside scss it becomes:

```
image-path('marker-icon-2x.png')
```

because folders `app/assets/[images||stylesheets||javascripts]` are map like one folder `/assets` with [asset pipeline framework](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

note that helper `image_tag('marker-icon-2x.png')` "knows" already where the image is

Answer (score 3):

I've added the urls as a data attribute to the `#map` element, here from my slim template:

```
#map data-marker-url=asset_path('leaflet/marker-icon.png') data-marker-2x-url=asset_path('leaflet/marker-icon-2x.png') data-marker-shadow-url=asset_path('leaflet/marker-shadow.png')
```

Then I access the values when setting the marker (`latitude` & `longitude` are also data attributes, but I skipped that for brevity)

```
$map = $('#map')
L.marker(
  [latitude, longitude],
  icon: new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: $map.data('marker-url'),
    retinaUrl: $map.data('marker-2x-url'),
    shadowUrl: $map.data('marker-shadow-url'),
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [12, 41],
    popupAnchor: [1, -34],
    shadowSize: [41, 41] 
  })  
).addTo(map)
```

The last 4 attributes set some meta data for the images, otherwise the image center will be set to that location and not the tip of the marker. These values are the defaults for leaflet 0.6.4.

Instead of data attributes you also can send your javascript through `erb` or something, but I like this better.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because Leaflet tries to guess the images path. But [you can set the default marker images path](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/766#issuecomment-7741090) in your initializer code, like this:

```
L.Icon.Default.imagePath = 'path-to-your-leaflet-images-folder';
// your other Leaflet code
```

So in your case it would be:

```
L.Icon.Default.imagePath = '/assets'
```

But there is a problem with this approach, it doesn't work with digested images. So it's best to use a custom `Icon` and set the urls with rails helpers:

```
digested_icon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: "<%= asset_path 'marker-icon.png' %>"
  iconRetinaUrl: "<%= asset_path 'marker-icon-2x.png' %>"
  shadowUrl: "<%= asset_path 'marker-shadow.png' %>"
})
```

Then you would specify this custom icon whenever you add a new marker:

```
L.marker([45.5, -10.9], {icon: digested_icon})
```

Remember to add `.erb` extension to your coffee/js file for the helpers to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display the images in a view, then you have to use image_path in conjunction with **image_tag**. image_path() only returns the pathname of the image file. So, you would do this:

```
image_tag image_path('your_image.png')
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using DropZone.js.  Instead of messing w/ the huge DropZone file, I just created a folder in /public named 'images' and placed my sprite images there.  That is where DropZone expects them, and is why I was getting a '404' Not Found error for the sprite images.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that if you have just added the /app/assets/images folder, sprockets won't find it until you restart your app.